# VFD parameter calculation for 3 phase motor

Tags: induction-motor, vfd

I have a small (¼ hp) motor that am going to hook up to a VFD. The VFD is programmable, and I'm planning to run the motor at 16-65 Hz with ∆ configuration.

The question is: what is a good ball park voltage to use at the lowest frequency (16 Hz), and what is a good ballpark intermediate frequency and voltage?

Right now I have set it to 50 V at the lowest frequency (16 Hz), 110 V at 40 Hz, and 220 V at 65 Hz.

The load on the motor is low, it is just driving a 6" blower fan wheel.

Is there a standard formula for calculating this? I presume there is, because I have another VFD driven motor where the VFD automagically calculated those parameters from motor plate data.

Here is the motor plate:

[image: motor plate]

...and this is the VFD parameters that I am unsure about:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the default UF curve in the VFD is incorrect? Just enter the nameplate details and set the reference frequency to 16 Hz.

Comment: This VFD don't have parameters for the motor nameplate details. Instead, it has "min frequency" (default 0 Hz), "min voltage" (default 0 V), max frequency (default 65 Hz), max voltage (default 220 V), intermediate frequency (default 25 Hz), intermediate voltage (default 110 V).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a first approximation:

The motor is designed to operate at 250 Volts at 60 Hz.  So we will make this our baseline.  The flux at this baseline gives us the best torque/speed performance.

We want the flux to stay at this baseline. Since the flux in our theoretical motor is inversely proportional to frequency, we should adjust the motor voltage proportionally to the target frequency to keep the flux constant at our baseline level.  So for 40 Hz, you should have a first guess of 250*40/60, or 167V.

To run at 65 Hz, you would need 270 volts using this approach.  If you can't generate the voltage, expect a rapid decrease in torque capability.  At your lowest frequency, the winding resistance will play a larger role, but this approach is still good for first approximation.

Comment: Great, thanks! The VFD's max output voltage is the same as the input voltage (no boost capability), and we are usually getting around 225-228V from the grid. Since the load is low (just a fan wheel attached directly to the motor axle), I think a loss of torque at higher frequencies should be ok. Would you recommend that I increase the voltage at the lowest frequency (16 Hz) from 50 V to 67V?  Most of the time, it will run at around 30-35Hz, and only occassionally will it run at the higher or lower ends of the frequency band.

Comment: I think with a fan running at low speed, you shouldn't have much torque so you won't have much slip.    Most likely a small increase in voltage like you suggest won't make much difference to the speed at the low end, but you can try and find out.

Comment: Thanks again John. My main concern is to avoid overheating the motor. I ran it for 2h at 40Hz today, and at least the exterior of the motor didn't get very hot so I think this should be ok.